# Why are xlwings UDF not compatible with OSX?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, xlwings

I've developed a software using xlwings for windows. It mostly relies on UDFs (user defined functions), which are only available on this platform.

Now that I've considered expanding to OSX, I was wondering why this feature was restricted to windows.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, UDFs work via COM server. That's a Windows specific technology that the `pywin32` package supports, i.e. the low level work has already been done, so xlwings can focus on making Excel and Python communicate through it (that on its own is still a lot of work).

On Mac, there is no readily available low-level solution for the Excel/Python communication which means that *somebody* has to build it first. This is a lot of work which is the reason why it's not there yet.